# How to convert JsonNode to ObjectNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `com.fasterxml JsonNode` object with some data. I need to do some manipulation on its data. I googled for answer but didn't got it properly. Can you please suggest me how to manipulate JsonNode data. 
I have also tried to convert `JsonNode` to `ObjectNode` as follows

```
ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode)filterJson;
```

but its giving following exception....

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode cannot be cast to 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
```

please help!!

Comment: Chances are you are trying to convert the value of ObjectNode to an objectNode. ObjectNode means {"test":"value"} and you are probably typecasting value node. If you can share the code, may be suggestions can be made on which node you should cast

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution as follows...

```
JsonNode jsonNode = Json.toJson("Json String");
ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonNode.asText());
//perform operations on node
jsonNode = (JsonNode) new ObjectMapper().readTree(node.toString());
```

or another one as below...

```
ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) new ObjectMapper().readTree("Json String")
//perform operations on node
jsonNode = (JsonNode) new ObjectMapper().readTree(node.toString());
```

but I don't know if this is good approach or not ?
If there is any better than above, please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: I think you are supposed to call JsonNode.isObject() to make sure you can cast before casting.

Comment: Definitely, it's worth checking the type before. 
Imagine that incoming String is not an expected JSON value but literally, a number f.ex "737". Then readTree() would convert it into IntNode object which cannot be cast into ObjectNode what will result with ClassCastException.

Comment: I'm facing the similar problem, my string is coming as a number "71" and readTree() method is converting it into IntNode object and it is throwing ClassCastException. How to convert IntNode into ObjectNode in that case?

Comment: Add the following import for the above to work,
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

Answer (score 56):

You can convert a `JsonNode` in an `ObjectNode` in this simple way:

```
ObjectNode objectNode = jsonNode.deepCopy();
```

[Available from Jackson 2.0](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#deepCopy()) and tested with Jackson 2.4.0

Answer (score 5):

I had this error too although in my case it was a stupid mistake.
I accidentally imported `org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode` instead of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`.
Using the jackson ObjectNode fixed the issuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can covert JsonNode to ObjectNode this way:

```
JsonNode demoPath = requestParams.at("/Subscription/0");
((ObjectNode) demoPath).put("mylID", "test12");
```

Answer (score -2):

I try it some times, it will be ok! You only define a `Student Class` to map the properties. Then you could convert the `jsonNode` to `Student` Object.

`Student student = objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode1, Student.class);`

I think this will be suitable for your need!

Comment: The question is how to convert a JsonNode in a com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode, not in a some Object instance