# merging two ObjectNode

Tags: java, jackson, jsonnode

I want to merge two *ObjectNode* together, but with the best complexity.
I aware about one way, I can use *setAll* method, but it returns JsonNode, therefore I must convert it. The best way that I found for the conversion procedure was [How to convert JsonNode to ObjectNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713109/how-to-convert-jsonnode-to-objectnode). I think this conversion once iterate over Json and maybe we can find a better solution.

The second way that I think is iterate over the second *ObjectNode* and add one by one to first *ObjectNode* with *put* method
But both of these solutions have cost, what is the best way to merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find the best way. Based on [How to modify JsonNode in Java? (Casting JsonNode to ObjectNode)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30997696/10514096) it seems we can easily cast JsonNode to ObjectNode thus I think below code will work(I didn't test yet):
consider we have two JSONs(JsonNode):

```
jsonNode json1;//initilized
jsonNode json2;//initilized
JsonNode mergedJson = ((JsonObject)json2).setAll(json1);
```

and if we want to treat mergedJson as JsonObject, again we can merge and do